Firestore pricing related to collectionReferences
How many reads are counted for the following query?
fireClient.Collections(ctx).GetAll()

will the following query result in 1 read or will it depend on the number of subcollections?
fireclient.Collection("users").Doc("user_id").Collections(ctx).GetAll()

I am trying to list down the subcollections within a document. I want to know the pricing for the same?
Edit:  Get All function - go docs

When you call GetAll() in this line:
fireClient.Collections(ctx).GetAll()

You will get all root collections and when you call GetAll() in this line:
fireclient.Collection("users").Doc("user_id").Collections(ctx).GetAll()

You'll get all sub-collections of the user_id document.
In both situations, you'll get an array of collection references. This means that you only read the names of the collections and not the actual documents within them. So since you aren't reading any documents, there is nothing you should pay. That's the reason why you cannot find anything related to this in the pricing section.

Thanks for answering!
just a follow up question, the following query will also results in no read operation
fireClient.Collection("users").Doc("user_id") , since i am just creating a document reference

If you're only creating a reference, there is also nothing to pay. If you, however, call Get() then you'll have to pay a document read.
